# Grid template with an inner overflow-x element break layout in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-grid

I’m having issues tracking the problem of a div that contains a big table (a green div in the fiddle). I want this div to have a working `overflow-x: auto`.

On firefox I don’t see any issues, the table container when the windows is too little adds a scrollbar, with chrome or opera the browser scrollbar is shown alongside the block scrollbar, and the page content extends over the window length.

If I don’t use Grid, all browsers show the same behavior, with a scrollbar only in the parent block of the table.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knmfuw96/) and snippet:

```css
.content {
  grid-area: content;
  display: block;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 6em);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: grey;
}

.sidemenu {
  height: 3em;
  grid-area: sidemenu;
  background-color: grey;
 }

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidemenu"
    "content"
    "footer";
}

.big {
  background-color: green;
  width: 2980px;
  height: 20px;
}
.blockWrapper { overflow-x: auto; }

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 3em 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "sidemenu content"
      "sidemenu footer";
  }
  .sidemenu { height: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidemenu"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="blockWrapper">
      <div class="big"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @kukkuz Please note that migrating substantive content from a 3rd party site w/ no license over to Stack Overflow is a violation of OP's license rights. If it's not pure boilerplate, you should ask OP to make the determination to license the content under SO's license rather than assuming they want it here.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you, you mean the fiddle code created as snippet?

Comment: @TylerH do I need to revert my edit?

Comment: @kukkuz No, it's too late now, as the code would still be present in the history and thus "on" the site. it would take a moderator redaction to remove it from the site, and even then I'm not sure that's allowed/enough to satisfy the license issue.

Comment: It's a boilerplate, I posted the fiddle because I was already meddling with the code on jsfiddle to figure out if with the minimun css the problem was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `width: 100%` and `margin: 0 auto` on `.content` to get the same behavior in Chrome & Firefox - see demo below:

```css
.content {
  grid-area: content;
  display: block;
  max-width: 1200px;
  /*margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 6em);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: grey;
}

.sidemenu {
  height: 3em;
  grid-area: sidemenu;
  background-color: grey;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "sidemenu" "content" "footer";
}

.big {
  background-color: green;
  width: 2980px;
  height: 20px;
}

.blockWrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 3em 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "sidemenu content" "sidemenu footer";
  }
  .sidemenu {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidemenu"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="blockWrapper">
      <div class="big"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

---

Another *fix* can be to specify `grid-template-columns: 100%` and `grid-template-columns: 3em calc(100% - 3em)` for the *media query* above 500px - see demo below:

```css
.content {
  grid-area: content;
  display: block;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 6em);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: grey;
}

.sidemenu {
  height: 3em;
  grid-area: sidemenu;
  background-color: grey;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "sidemenu" "content" "footer";
  grid-template-columns: 100%; /* added */
}

.big {
  background-color: green;
  width: 2980px;
  height: 20px;
}

.blockWrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 3em 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "sidemenu content" "sidemenu footer";
    grid-template-columns: 3em calc(100% - 3em); /* added */
  }
  .sidemenu {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidemenu"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="blockWrapper">
      <div class="big"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the second fix is the one I was looking for, I tried a lot of different solution, even with a combinations of grid-template-columns and different widths, but never with 100%. Thank you!